# Showing Interstitial ad at regular intervals

Tags: android, kotlin, ads, interstitial

```
//Inside onCreate()
var adRequest2 = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-myAppId", adRequest2, object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                Log.d(TAG, adError?.message)
                mInterstitialAd = null
            }
            override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Ad was loaded.")
                mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd
            }

        })
//Inside onItemSelectedListener of spinner 
 if (counter%3==0){
                    if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                        mInterstitialAd?.show(this@MainActivity)
                    } else {
                        Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.")
                    }
                }
 counter++
```

I have an app which displays some data based on what the user selects from a dropdown menu/spinner. I want to display an interstitial ad for every 3 items chosen on the spinner. I used this bit of code from the google admob website. But this only shows the ad once after the 3rd choice. It doesn't reload on 6th,9th... and so on. How can I make the interstitial ad reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reload ad each time you've showed it : Like create a loadAd function and call it each time in the onItemSelectListener

LoadAd Function

```
fun loadIADS(){
var adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()

      InterstitialAd.load(this,"your_ID", adRequest, object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
        override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
          Log.d(TAG, adError?.message)
          mInterstitialAd = null
        }

        override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
          Log.d(TAG, 'Ad was loaded.')
          mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd
        }
      })
}
```

Show ads

```
fun showIADS(){
if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
  mInterstitialAd?.show(this)
} else {
  Log.d("TAG", " ad wasn't ready ")
}
}
```

In Oncreate instead of initialzing just put this

```
counter = 0
loadIADS()
```

and in onItemSelectedListener LIke you have

```
if (counter%3==0){
                    showIADS()
                }
loadIADS()
 counter++
```

I just had converted my java code to kotlin tell me if it shows error